# How to freeze the top row and the first column using XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am exporting a pandas `DataFrame` to Excel, and since it contains a lot of rows and columns, it would be useful to keep the top row and the first column when browsing its contents.

There is a feature present in Excel that allows for freezing the top row and the first column. Is accessible through `XlsxWriter` when [exporting DataFrames to excel](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `worksheet.freeze_panes()` to achieve this . There are many options for that method. Read http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-freeze-panes to know how to use the method.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the suggested `worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 1)` and it worked.

Answer (score 18):

For those who would like to freeze the top row and/or column when exporting a pandas DataFrame to Excel, without interfacing with the underlying engine, `to_excel()` provides a way to do so via `freeze_panes` keyword argument.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
df.to_excel("pandas_simple.xlsx", freeze_panes=(1, 1))
```